# Choppy SVG rendering during rotation in Mobile Safari

Tags: css, svg, mobile-safari, css-transforms

Got a really tricky problem that I've been trying to figure out for a while. Essentially I'm building a large rotating wheel which has multiple elements rotating at different speeds. It's about 5000px square, but the viewport is a percentage of window height. Due to the scaling, the wheel itself is an SVG so that it looks sharp on all devices. The SVG has some pretty complicated paths in places.

It's hard to explain, so I've made a barebones demo of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/UsVeZ/3/embedded/result/ (edit it here: http://jsfiddle.net/UsVeZ/13/). Click / tap the document to see it rotate.

Everything looks fine, and it works great on the desktop (Chrome + Safari), but when I rotate the wheel on an iPad, mobile safari lags with the rendering. The rotating animation itself is pretty smooth, but it's just the rendering that can't keep up. It's way worse with my complex SVG (which unfortunately I'm not permitted to share, but the demo gives an idea).  Check it out on an iPad to see what I mean.

I'm not quite sure how to solve this problem - ideally it would be great if there was some way to keep the entire SVG in memory (not sure exactly how the rendering works or why it's doing what it's doing). If anyone has any ideas, or even a different way to approach, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't end up solving this issue properly on my real example. I ended up reverting to images (I split up my large image into 9 smaller images and tiled them to get around iOS' 5mp limit), and on each image I applied the following property which seems to cache the image:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

It doesn't scale as nicely, but it works smoothly which is more important.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, just a couple of strategies you could follow.

If you apply...

```
body {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
}
```

You will see how Mobile Safari caches your svg, it gets pixelated and then renders correctly. If you tap and wait, it will re-cache the image when you tap again. But if you tap continously, you will notice you don't give it a chance to recache the image.

This happens in your jsfiddle too, if you tap continously eventually you don't get any choppy blocks.

So if you don't let Safari recache the image by creating an endless transition like...

```
$("svg").on("webkitTransitionEnd", function(){
  rotation -= .01;
  $("#large").css('-webkit-transform', "translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(" + rotation + "deg)");
  $("#small").css('-webkit-transform', "translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(" + ( rotation * 1.5 ) + "deg)");
});
```

Then the cache will never go stale.

However, once you remove the scale on the body, it seems that Safari won't cache any graphics outside of the viewport. So, perhaps if you make the wheel have a full spin on load it will cache the image.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas again, you've been really helpful :). I tried out some of those ideas, but nothing seemed to work, so I reverted to images.

Answer (score 0):

I actually took several different SVG's and applied a rotation to them in iOS and it ends up adding this box the instant I rotate it.  I can't duplicate it in Safari or Chrome (desktop).  Tried a bunch of different things to get it to stop, but no luck.  I haven't been able to find much feedback online about if its a bug or not.

Just applying -webkit-transform: rotate(122deg);

Example at - http://bit.ly/QnAgFK

I found that certain [object] tags have there #documents add [html][body] tags around the svg in Safari 6.  Others don't.  So my assumption is this is a mime type host issue, but I've got the image/svg+xml mime-type added for .svg.

Comment: Example link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a dirty fix for this one.

```
#topParentId *{
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d !important;
}
```

I have applied css to every child of topParentId Id, and this works fine for me. It changes a little css in output but it works fine for me.